# Html Bootstrap Columns stacking not side by side

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Hi y'all I'm trying to understand why my columns are stacking on top of each other instead of being side by side.
Here's a screenshot of my page: Everything above the shopping cart I want to be to the right of the main page content like a side bar but I'm struggling to make that happen
[image]

And here is my html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
            <app-grocery-sidebar></app-grocery-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
            <recipes></recipes>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Whops I meant everything above the shopping cart needs to be to the left of the main page recipes content. but i guess it doesn't matter as long as they are side by side

Comment: the items would go in a column, not rows; You create 3 columns under a `.row` and then fill your data inside them; this can help: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap grid system has 12 columns per row. If the total number of columns is greater than 12, then the spare columns will wrap into the next row.

In your example, for small screens you have 2 x `col-sm-9` classes, which makes a total of 18 columns. For medium screens you have 2 x `col-md-6` classes, which makes a total of 12 columns, so it should work fine for this screen size, each column should have the same width. For large screens you have 2 x `col-lg-8` classes, which makes a total of 16 columns.

You need to decide what % of the screen you want your sidebar to take up on large screens. For example, say you want it to take 25% of the screen, then you should give `col-lg-3` to the sidebar and `col-lg-9` to the recipes. If you want this to be the case on all screen sizes, then use `col-3` and `col-9` respectively.

If you want to give 33% of the screen to you sidebar, then you should use `col-lg-4` and `col-lg-8` respectively.

`col-lg-2`and `col-lg-10` will give 16.6% of the screen to the sidebar and 83.3% of the screen to the recipes.

`col-md-6` for both, will give each element equal width of the screen on medium sized screens.

If you want all columns to take up equal space, you can also just use the `col` class on each element.

Read more on the Bootstrap docs for their [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).